Fetch data from website / API after login
There are several questions and answers on Stack Overflow how to fetch data from a website / API to a Google spreadsheet using Google Apps Script where it is needed to login to the website first.
The process is as follows:

The username and password are either hardcoded in the script or entered by the user in a SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt()
The login is done via UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/login",Options) with the method and username and password as options
A cookie or token is received from the login page and the second fetch to get the relevant data (from the webpage or API) is done via UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://example.com/data/",Options) with the cookie / token and the relevant data for the API in the options

Steps 2 & 3 are fine. But in step 1 it seems very unsafe to me to hardcode passwords in the script or let users enter them via a prompt because all editors of the script could manipulate it and get the password.
Is there no other possibility to work with the password?
For example to somehow redirect the user to the reel login page ("https://example.com/login") and get just the cookie / token from there? But mostly these login pages dont allow to be implemented in an iframe which could be displayed in a html-dialog.
Its an even bigger problem when the manual login to the website is done via SSO and users are not used to enter their password. That would take a lot of explanations why they need to enter their password in e.g. the prompt in the spreadsheet file.
Any suggestions to make this more secure and convinient?

I have limited information about your code, project, and overall goal. However, based on what I understand, you are looking for an alternative way to manage input with more control. Here are the following options:
1.) Web Apps: You can use Google Apps Script to create a web app. This approach provides a separate link from your Google document and offers greater control over how you handle your data.
2.) Google Add-ons (Card Services): This option allows you to regain some control without completely detaching from the current services you are using.

Thanks for your proposal. Your options would be better than my current solution, because I dont need to share the code, just the final URL to the web app or the Addon, and no one else can manipulate the code.  But in both cases the users need to trust that the password which they enter in the web app or the Add-On is just used for the login and not saved or transfered somewhere else. In terms of security I was hoping for better options

I was hoping to gain more information about this part of your comment In terms of security I was hoping for better options , I am wondering if new implementation is what you need like shared on above comments or are you looking for something specific topics. I do think that this is more on software design part of things But in both cases the users need to trust that the password which they enter in the web app or the Add-On is just used for the login and not saved or transferred somewhere else

I am looking for a general way to implement a URL fetch where login credentials are needed in a secure way without hard coding passwords or letting users input their passwords in script prompts, because all of that seems pretty unsecure to me
